# Find diagonals in a Python matrix using lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to code the game connect-4, and there is a part of my code in which i try to find in a 7x6 matrix, diagonals of 4 ones in a row or 4 2s in a row.
This part of my code does not work i tried everything I was able to. And sometimes it detects that there is a 4 1s or 4 2s diagonal where is not. I created the matrix puting a 7 zero list in each position of a 6 zeros lists. I'm trying to do it using only lists functions, i cant use the numpy library or similar. 
Okay, in this part of the code I'm trying to find if in each possible diagonal of the matrice there are 4 zeros in a row. PD: I'm only trying to find the diagonals that go from left to right ATM. Thanks for your help, I tried to explain my problem as good as I can because english is not my main tongue.
This is my code:

```
import random
llista = [0]*6 #when i say llista y mean matrix
for i in range(6):
    llista[i]=[0]*7

#Here i fill the 7*6 matrix of 0s 1s and 2s randomly so i can see if it works.
for i in range(30):
    x=random.randrange(-1,-7,-1)
    y=random.randrange(0,7,1)
    llista[x][y]=1
for i in range(30):
    x=random.randrange(-1,-7,-1)
    y=random.randrange(0,7,1)
    llista[x][y]=2
#This 2 loops here are too see if it is possible to have a diagonal in the matrece because if you want a diagonal u need at least a one or 2 in the center, the problem is not here.
for i in range(-1,-7,-1):
    possible = False
    if llista[i][3]==1:
        possible = True
        break

for i in range(7):
    possible2 = False
    if llista[-4][i]==1 or llista[-4][i]==1:
        possible2=True
        break

if possible==True and possible2==True:
#The problem starts here. This first loop i use it too find the diagonals that go from left to right. I want to find diagonals of 4 1s or 4 2s.
for i in range(len(llista)-3):
    for j in range(len(llista[i])-3):
        #This if is too see if we have four 1 or 2 togheter in the list, if we have them it prints the sentence below.
        if (llista[i][j]==1 and llista[i+1][j+1]==1 and llista[i+2][j+2]==1 and llista[i+3][j+3]==1)  or (llista[i][j]==2 and llista[i+1][j+1]==2 and llista[i+2][j+2]==2 and llista[i+3][j+3]==2 ):
            print("There is at least one left to right diagonal")

#This loop is the same than the last one but to find diagonals from right to left (a 4 diagonal made of 1s or 2s)
    for i in range(len(llista)):
        for j in range(len(llista[i])):
            if i-3<0 and j-3<0:
                if (llista[i][j]==1 and llista[i-1][j-1]==1 and llista[i-2][j-2]==1 and llista[i-3][j-3]==1)  or (llista[i][j]==2 and llista[i-1][j-1]==2 and llista[i-2][j-2]==2 and llista[i-3][j-3]==2 ):
                   print("There is at least one right to left diagonal")

#Here i print the matrix
for i in range(6):
    print(llista[i])
#So this program should say if there is at least one left to right diagonal
```

or right to left diagonal.
     #I dont want to use functions that are not being used already, and i dont wanna do it another way because i must understand this way. thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: I'm not getting any error message, it says that there is a diagonal even if there is not a 4 ones or 2s diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the logic of your 'right-to-left' loop, you are actually just doing the same as your 'left-to-right' loop in reverse order. To really get the 'right-to-left' pass right you have to have your `i` and `j` indices moving in different directions.

So your conditional statement in this section should look like:

```
if i-3>=0 and j+3<7:
    if (llista[i][j]==1 and llista[i-1][j+1]==1 and llista[i-2][j+2]==1 and llista[i-3][j+3]==1)  or (llista[i][j]==2 and llista[i-1][j+1]==2 and llista[i-2][j+2]==2 and llista[i-3][j+3]==2 ):
        print("There is at least one right to left diagonal")
```

There are a ton of optimizations you could use by importing libraries like `numpy` or `itertools` as AResem showed. That answer is not entirely correct though for the following reason.

When you say `return True, k` you are not exercising any control over the value of `k` because it was used in the list comprehension just above and will just have the value of the last item it iterated over. So when your function finds a diagonal it reports the wrong number about two thirds of the time.

Here is an edited function that gives the correct results:

```
def check_diagonals(matrix):
    for offset in range(-2, 4):
        diag = matrix.diagonal(offset=offset)

        # Here you can create a tuple of numbers with the number of times they are repeated. 
        # This allows you to keep your k and g values associated.
        repeat_groups = [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in  groupby(diag)]

        # By using the built-in max function with the 'key' keyword, you can find 
        # the maximum number of repeats and return the number associated with that.
        num, max_repeats = max(repeat_groups, key=lambda item: item[1])
        if max_repeats >= 4:
            return True, num
    return False, None
```

If you run this function with `print` statements added you can get output like the following:

```
Matrix: 
[[1 0 2 2 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 2 1 1 1]
 [2 2 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 2 2 0 2 2]
 [2 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [2 2 0 2 1 0 2]]

offset -2
diag [2 0 1 2]
repeat_groups [(2, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
num, max_repeats 2 1

offset -1
diag [0 2 2 1 1]
repeat_groups [(0, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
num, max_repeats 2 2

offset 0
diag [1 2 0 2 1 0]
repeat_groups [(1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (0, 1)]
num, max_repeats 1 1

offset 1
diag [0 0 0 0 1 2]
repeat_groups [(0, 4), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
num, max_repeats 0 4
(True, 0)
There is at least one left to right diagonal: 0's' # Correct!
```

If you want to ignore diagonals of zeros, you can easily add an extra condition, e.g.

```
if max_repeats >= 4 and num != 0:
    return True, num
```

You could try and recreate this without using `numpy` if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for ur help berkelem I really appreciate the time u spend helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not getting the right answer because of the way you parsed your conditional statements.
You should have

```
if cond1 or cond2:
    # do something
```

with the conditions contained in parentheses `()`. At the moment only your second condition is contained in parentheses. 
Try the following:

```
if (matrix[i][j]==1 and matrix[i+1][j+1]==1 and matrix[i+2][j+2]==1 and matrix[i+3][j+3]==1)  or (matrix[i][j]==2 and matrix[i+1][j+1]==2 and matrix[i+2][j+2]==2 and matrix[i+3][j+3]==2 ):
    print("There is at least one left to right diagonal")
```

Comment: I changed that and sometimes it says that there is a diagonal even if is not there.

Comment: Could you post more of your code? It should help pinpoint where the problem is. Otherwise we're just guessing where the problem might be.

Comment: I posted another answer below. I initially copied the wrong code so you have a corrected version of AResem's answer as well as a correction for your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using numpy for this problem. Here goes some code to get you started.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

def check_diagonals(matrix):
    for offset in range(-2, 4):
        diag = matrix.diagonal(offset=offset)
        if max([sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in  groupby(diag)]) >= 4:
            return True, k
    return False, None

# random test matrix
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 3, 6 * 7)
matrix = matrix.reshape(6,7)

# left to right check
resp_tuple = check_diagonals(matrix)
if resp_tuple[0]:
    print("There is at least one left to right diagonal: {}'s'".format(resp_tuple[1]))
else:
    # right to left
    resp_tuple = check_diagonals(np.fliplr(matrix))
    if resp_tuple[0]:
        print("There is at least one right to left diagonal:     {}'s'".format(resp_tuple[1]))
    else:
        # No diagonals
        print('No diagonals')
```

Comment: Thnak you, but, like I said using numpy is not an option because I'm new at coding and i must understand how to find it without the numpy function, only using lists. Thanks